# Cannot access salesforce namespaced protected custom metadata

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-metadata

I created a namespaced protected custom metadata to store API keys, it is working fine in my scratch orgs. However, when I am packaging it as 1GP and installing the beta package in a developer test org I cannot read the custom metadata. Also, since it is managed I cannot see any debug logs (separate issue)

I created a LWC to insert my API keys and I believe it is getting inserted fine. I spool the deploy result in an email.

```
DeployResult:[canceledBy=000000000000000, canceledByName=null, checkOnly=false, completedDate=2022-06-14 18:28:15, createdBy=0053t000007T2kO, createdByName=asarkar@aunt-bertha.org, createdDate=2022-06-14 18:28:07, details=DeployDetails:[componentFailures=(), componentSuccesses=(DeployMessage:[changed=true, columnNumber=null, componentType=CustomMetadata, created=true, createdDate=2022-06-14 18:28:15, deleted=false, fileName=customMetadata/svc_onedegree__One_Degree_API_Key__mdt.API_Keys.md, fullName=svc_onedegree__One_Degree_API_Key__mdt.API_Keys, id=m043t000000dqFTAAY, lineNumber=null, problem=null, problemType=null, success=true], DeployMessage:[changed=true, columnNumber=null, componentType=null, created=false, createdDate=2022-06-14 18:28:15, deleted=false, fileName=package.xml, fullName=package.xml, id=null, lineNumber=null, problem=null, problemType=null, success=true])], done=true, errorMessage=null, errorStatusCode=null, id=0Af3t00000BxY9HCAV, ignoreWarnings=false, lastModifiedDate=2022-06-14 18:28:15, messages=((already output), (already output)), numberComponentErrors=0, numberComponentsDeployed=1, numberComponentsTotal=1, rollbackOnError=true, startDate=2022-06-14 18:28:14, stateDetail=null, status=Succeeded, success=true]
```

Now when I am trying to read the metadata in my apex the API keys are blank. This is how I am accessing it

```
List<One_Degree_API_Key__mdt> apiKeys = One_Degree_API_Key__mdt.getAll().values();
System.debug(apiKeys[0].Google_API_Key__c);
```

I am pretty sure the API keys are not fetched. How do I read a namespaced protected metadata in my apex.